# Why a is pulse in units of 1/Hz/sec

Tags: pulse

I don't understand the unit of the pulse shown below.
Hz by definition is 1/sec.
If it's in time domain then BW is in seconds.
If it's in frequency domain its Hz.

What is the logical meaning of the combination between the two?
1/hz/sec?

[image]

[image]

Comment: the pulse is not in "per second per Hertz"; it's (at least to me) not clear how you come up with that result. The text you show does not imply that.

Comment: what is 1 pulse/sec/hz

Comment: that's the question. It doesn't arrive from the things on the slide. I'm sorry, we don't have the context to these slides that you have

Comment: Please edit your question with a citation of your slide deck.  If it's on the web, include a link.  If it's not on the web, or if it's long, give us the title, a synopsis, and maybe some more background.

Answer (score 1):

Pulse per second refers to the rate of sending pulses (data). How much bandwidth such a data rate takes up is the bandwidth efficiency. If for example we could send a data rate of 1 pulse per second in one Hz of bandwidth, the efficiency in this case would be 1 pulse/sec per Hz.